# Standard form and basic solutions

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Is it possible that for a general linear program none of the optimal solutions have to be basic? Meanwhile, for a program in **standard form** an optimal solution has be basic. If so, why ?

Answer (score 0):

For $$\min_{x \geq 0} \{ x : x \leq 1\}$$ the only basic feasible solution is $x=1$, which is not optimal.

Comment: Why $x = 0$ is not a basic feasible solution?  If I add a slack variable $s \ge 0$, then $x + s = 1$.  The optimal solution $(x,s) = (0,1)$ has one non-zero entry, so it's basic.

Comment: @GNUSupporter That's a different polygon. I am looking at $Ax \leq b$, not $Ax + s = b$ (even though its projection on $x$ is the same). Also see [this definition](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~yaron/AM221/lecture_notes/AM221_lecture7.pdf) of basic feasible solution.

Comment: This is not clear to me. I thought that a basic solution is the same beetween standard form and general form of a linear program...

Comment: basic solutions relates to polyhedra in standard form

Comment: @MarcelloSammarra my previous comment contains a reference that states the opposite of what you are saying. Another reference is Definition 2.9 in Introduction to linear optimization by Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis.